# Best option for a editable dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-interface

I want a dropdown menu that allows user to type in text..something like autocomplete with dropdown.

I have been trying this for a long time now and while going through other posts I found people suggesting Ajax but I could not use it.

What are the other options available ?

also,I have to bind the dropdown to a database query so the option must allow that.Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try one of these two :

[Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

[Select2](https://select2.github.io/)

Try using this code:

```
$("#DropDOwnID").select2({
    ajax: {
        url: "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/search",  //method which returns the data for select2 OR in web forms use  web service
        type: 'GET',
        multiple: true, //if dropdown can have multiple or not
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                parametername: params.term, // search 
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data, page) {
            // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
            // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
            // alter the remote JSON data
            var myResults = [];
            $.each(data.data, function (index, item) {
                myResults.push({
                    'id': item.key,
                    'text': item.name
                });
            });
            return {
                results: myResults
            };
        },
        cache: true
    },
    minimumInputLength: 1,
});
```

Comment: Hi Rohit...I tried using Select2.I did what was written beneath the heading Downloading the code locally but no where its explained how do I use it in the dropdown..I saw the examples and included the script in my code..but what after that ?

Comment: if you are using version 3.5.2

Comment: As I have mentioned in the question,the items in the dropdown will come from a database query..it looks like html element..can i do data binding in this ?

Comment: Yes you can use ajax function in this select2.

Comment: This might help you :  http://www.southcoastweb.co.uk/jquery-select2-ajax-tutorial/

Comment: But i suggest you to use version 4.0(Latest), its documentations are available on main website of select 2.

Comment: This link isn't opening

Comment: I will try understanding how to link it to the database.It looks complicated..I will read and get back to u.

Comment: Rohit,I am a little new to this..can u please tell me exactly where is the database part..thanks a ton

Comment: I am now getting it without the database..i used this code :http://runnable.com/Umt4ZM6SgSFGAAAp/basic-usage-of-select2-for-jquery

Comment: implementing it in MVC ?

Comment: Then create a web service,WCF or Web Api and call it in url of above method which will return you the entire list. Here's the link : http://www.datahaunting.com/jquery/select2-remote-data-example-in-asp-net-web-forms/

Comment: I have not heard half of these terms before :( :( There isn't any simpler solution ?

Comment: might be , but i am not aware about any else method.

Comment: so i will put asp:dropdown and store database results in some array results...is that correct ?

Comment: can i bind a sqldatasource to it ?

Comment: so how do i take the results of database query as the items in this dropdown ?

Comment: Create a web service which returns as items as json result. and then handle it in processResults of select2 method written above.

Comment: Yeh mujhse NHP :P Thanks for all your help :) I would have upvoted your answer too..but not enough reputation :P

Comment: No problem , anyways all the best.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Select2 https://select2.github.io/
It has Ajax \ plain HTML mode, as well as ability to create pagination for large quantity of items.
You can create it using plain select as data source or even hidden input for ajax \ pagination